# Consulta sin repetir sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alguien me puede ayudar a obtener una consultar sin datos repetidos por "columna", ya probe el famoso DISTINCT pero solo quita los campos repetidos de todas las columnas que seleccione, 
SELECT DISTINCT RUC ,
RAZONSOCIAL ,
NOMBRECOMERCIAL ,
DOMICILIO ,
TELEFONO ,
email ,
web  FROM TEMP
Lo que necesito es que me muestre los campos sin repetir dependiendo del ruc.

Comment: Un consejo: cuando hagas preguntas de BD, procura incluir la estructura de las tablas involucradas (la sentencia DDL que crea cada una) y algunos datos de prueba. Y, si quieres hacer más fácil que otros repliquen tu problema, incluye esa información como texto, no como imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select 
  ruc, 
  RAZONSOCIAL, 
  NOMBRECOMERCIAL,
  DOMICILIO, 
  TELEFONO, 
  email, 
  web , COUNT(*) 
FROM TEMP 
GROUP BY ruc, RAZONSOCIAL, NOMBRECOMERCIAL, DOMICILIO, TELEFONO, email, web 
HAVING  COUNT()>1
```

El campo `count(*)` al final de la selección, mostará el número de registros que que tienen datos en  común(registros repetidos), en `having` puedo condicionarle me muestre por ejemplo `having count(*)=1` aquellos que son únicos, `having count(*)>1` aquellos que se repiten mas de una vez.

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código generalmente son de baja calidad, pues no dan guía clara, por favor añade una explicación

Comment: Hola, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque, sin una explicación clara, no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Sería ideal que editaras la respuesta para añadir una pequeña descripción de lo que hace el código y por qué serviría para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que sea algo así lo que quieres:

```
Select 
    ruc, 
    Max(RAZONSOCIAL) RAZONSOCIAL, 
    Max(NOMBRECOMERCIAL) NOMBRECOMERCIAL, 
    Max(DOMICILIO) DOMICILIO, 
    Max(TELEFONO) TELEFONO, 
    Max(email) email, 
    Max(web) web 
FROM TEMP 
GROUP BY ruc`
```

De lo contrario deberías explicar como son los datos de tu tabla, la clave primaria, las combinaciones de datos posibles, y cosas así...